# How to implement a check-in dance feature in Visual Studio 2012 with TFS 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-macros

We want a feature we feel would save our team a lot of time.

We have a build server that performs gated check-ins but it is old and heavily burdened. If we can avoid putting load on our build server then we need to.

When a developer tried to check in to TFS [also git, Mercurial if possible], visual studio should instead:

1. Get latest.
2. Clean the solution.
3. Build the solution.
4. Run all the smoke unit tests.
5. if they pass, then check in to TFS.

Does anyone know how to implement this in visual studio or with macros or an open source or commercial tool?

Answer (score 1):

In TFS you could add a few checkin policies to ensure the developer has built and run tests.

Here's some more information on checkin policies

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jjameson/archive/2009/10/31/recommended-check-in-policies-for-team-foundation-server.aspx

Comment: A better way would be to buy a newer server! But the above will work too :)